# Docker Nginx with custom config file: unknown directive "server"

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to implement a Django / Gunicorn / Nginx dockerized.
For Django gunicorn and postgresql everything works very well. But Nginx decided to not work.

I made a custom Nginx config file which gave me the error:

> unknown directive "server"

So I changed it at the maximum to try it with docker run in place of docker compose. I did a Dockerfile because it seems that the volume mount didn't work but same result.

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

And the nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Pretty simple. But still if I try to run this docker:

```
docker build -t nginx .
docker run nginx
```

Still the same error.

Here is the full logs on the run command:

> docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt
> to perform configuration /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell
> scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/ /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching
> /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
> 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of
> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh:
> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packages version,
> exiting /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching
> /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
> /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
> 2021/02/06 13:58:21 [emerg] 1#1: unknown directive "upstream" in
> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1 nginx: [emerg] unknown directive
> "upstream" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1

I spend almost 6 hours on that and probably read half of StackOverflow with no result.

Any life saving idea?

Comment: Guess: put `upstream` and `server` into `http` block?

Comment: I just tested your example, for me, it does work fine. I had to replace `web:8080` with something else such as `127.0.0.1:8080` because `web` was unknown, but after changing it, it works (shows me a `502 Bad Gateway`-message, as expected).

Comment: @qräbnö I tried that as well. It says unknown directive http

Comment: @SimonLeiß I updated my message to reflect more simple but same problem

Comment: @Tartempion34 I just retested it with the new config, it still works (now I get a different error "400 Bad Request - Request Header Or Cookie Too Large", but I still don't get the error you got).

Comment: That is crazy. Can it be a question of file encoding?

Comment: @SimonLeiß I pushed the image here: https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/aurelienmasse/docker
If you wanna try

Answer (score 0):

Ok Finally got it.

I removed the complete .conf file and did it without copy paste directly with vim and that works.

It seems that PyCharm saved it with a problem.